# Jotai - how to set an array state deriving from its previous value plus new values

Tags: reactjs, jotai

Right now, I have a state like this:

```
export const asyncComicsList = atom<Promise<Comics[]>>(async (get) => {
  const page = get(pagination)
  return getMarvelData({ resource: 'comics', page }).then(
    (res) => res.data.results as Comics[]
  )
})
export const loadableComicsList = loadable(asyncComicsList)
```

I hardcoded a limit of 10 itens per request. My site fetches 10 more whenever the user scrolls to the end of the page. In the component that maps the items, I have an useState/useEffect combination to keep all previous fetched items, like this:

```
export function Main(): JSX.Element {
  const [asyncComicsList] = useAtom(loadableComicsList)
  const [comics, setComics] = useState<Comics[]>([])

  useEndOfPageObserver()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (asyncComicsList.state === 'hasData') {
      setComics((prev) => [...prev, ...asyncComicsList.data])
    }
  }, [asyncComicsList.state])

  if (asyncComicsList.state === 'hasError') return <Error />

  return (
    <main className='grid gap-4 grid-cols-4'>
      {comics.map((comics) => (
        <ComicsCard comics={comics} key={comics.id} />
      ))}
      {asyncComicsList.state === 'loading' && <Loading />}
    </main>
  )
}
```

It works, but I'm trying to find a way to keep track of all items using only jotai's features and get rid of the useState/useEffect combo. Any idea would be appreciated.

I tried to use the argument **get** in the callback that is used in the creation of the atom, but it seems that it cannot access itself.